# Character limit in TinyMCE is not working

Tags: tinymce

i have implemented character limit from 
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=add&group_id=103281&atid=738747

i have given maxlength of 10 chars.when i am going to insert 11 char its inserting blank space. as i have also implemented how many chars are inserted. so it showing 11 chars in statusbar of TinyMCE.

please provide some solution for this or any alternate solution for character limit in TinyMCE.

Comment: sorry i put wrong link.                                           http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1951798&group_id=103281&atid=738747 .

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own plugin and check for onkey events and paste.

Then you could use

```
var text_content = $(ed.getBody()).text();

// you are looking for text_content.length

if (text_content.length > 10){
  // remove the characters 10+
}
```

Comment: have you implemented TinyMCE ? if you find or have demo/links then give me. so i can check those and try to implement. as i have tried to find in google but still some issuse. thanks.

Comment: i did, but i cannot show them to the puplic cause of enterprise issues