# html editor display issue

Tags: php, html, tinymce

We understand that html editor like tiny_mce can allow us to upload html expressions above plain text, which is able to cater `<td></td>`, `<div></div>`, `<p></p>`, etc.

If the entire codes entered the database are to be displayed in a webpage, everything is fine. However, if content chopping occurs due to design requirement, it may be possible that `</td>`, `</div>`, `</p>` will be chopped away, resulting in damaged page layout due to unclosed tag.

What is the normal practice to handle this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using tinymce for a while now and I have had this issue and you can make it so that the  field has a limit. [w3schools has a good explanation and solution.](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_textarea_maxlength.asp) It should work for your issue.

Comment: maxlength is applicable to a textarea, but not to the tinymce editor!  this SO question shows how to implement a character limit for the tinymce editor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255076/character-limit-in-tinymce-is-not-working